# Cannot read property of undefined error in mongoose method

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using node for requesting data using tokens for authentication but getting an error

> Error 500 : Cannot read property of undefined

Here is my code

**Function findByToken()**

```
var User = this;

    var decoded;

try {
    jwt.verify(token, 'abc');
} catch(e) {
    return Promise.reject();
}

return User.findOne({
    '_id': decoded._id,
    'tokens.token': token,
    'tokens.access': 'auth' 
});
```

This function takes token as an argument and find the data into database.

**Route**

```
app.get('/users/me', (req,res) => {

var token = req.header('x-auth');

User.findByToken(token).then((user) => {

    res.send(req.user);

}).catch((e) => {
    res.send(e);
});


});
```

This is the route where i am using my function to return the data. But getting a 500 error please help me with this.

Comment: findByToken is not a method on your User model but you are trying to call it as such

Answer (score 0):

You should use statics methods

For example:

```
animalSchema.statics.findByName = function(name, cb) {
return this.find({ name: new RegExp(name, 'i') }, cb);
};
```